# Align html form on the right (JQuery mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, alignment

I just want to move the HTML form on the right (under the map). I tried to use `align="right"` but nothing changes. Here is my full code. You can just run it to see how it looks: 
The map display is also odd but that's another issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Finding the best location</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/leaflet.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/leaflet.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/leaflet.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
<div data-role="content" >

        <h1>Location suitability application</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div id="mymap" style="height:300px;width:700px""></div>            

<form name="theform" >
        <table width="600"> 
        <tr>
            <td width="400" align="left">

            <td width="9"> 
            <td width="224"> 
            <b>Business importance factor:</b>
            <SELECT name="busfac"> 
            <OPTION selected value="1">1</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="2">2</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="3">3</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="4">4</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="5">5</OPTION>

            </SELECT>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="154" align="left">
            <td width="9">
            <td width="224">
            <b>Neighborhood importance factor:</b>
            <SELECT name="neifac">
            <OPTION selected value="1">1</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="2">2</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="3">3</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="4">4</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="5">5</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="154" align="left">
            <td width="9">
            <td width="224">    
            <input type="button" Value="Store point" 
            onclick="insertW(this.form.busfac.value,this.form.neifac.value);"/>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="154" align="left">
            <td width="9">
            <td width="224">    
            <input type="button" Value="Calculate best location" 
            onclick="nese(handleLoc);"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="154" align="left">
            <td width="9">
            <td width="224">    
            <p> Your Latitude is: <b id="C1" name="Latitude"> </b> </p>
            <p> Your Longitude is: <b id="C2" name="Longitude"> </b> </p>
        </tr>
        </table>




        <td width="154" align="left">
            <td width="9">
            <td width="224">    
            <input type="hidden" name="gjer" id="gjerId" />
        </tr>

        </form>

        <script>


function mark(p) {
theMarker=new L.Marker(p);
map.addLayer(theMarker);
theMarker.bindPopup("You are here");
}

function handleLoc(pos)  {
var a=pos.coords.latitude;
var b=pos.coords.longitude;
var p = new L.LatLng(+a, +b);
mark(p);
document.getElementById("C1").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("C2").innerHTML;
}



function handleErr(pos) {
document.write("could not determine location");
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleLoc, handleErr);
} else {
document.write("geolocation not supported");
}

var map = new L.Map('mymap');
var osmTile = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
var osmCopyleft = "Map data &copy;2012 OpenStreetMap contributors";

var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmTile, {
    attribution: osmCopyleft
});
map.addLayer(osmLayer);
map.setView(new L.LatLng(41.33,19.8), 13);


    </script> 
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **CSS** file, try:

```
float: right;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
First, I don't know anything about CSS.
The only script I created is the one containing the code above. In this script I have only included two CSS links -one for the JQuery mobile ["href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"] and one for the map ["href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/leaflet.css"].
Should I create those scripts, put them in my local folder and try to put your "float: right; ?

Comment: The closing DIV tag underneath your H1 is closing the CONTENT div, not the HEADER div as your comment in your code would suggest. This may be causing you problems.

Comment: Good observation! I fixed it. The page color changed from black to white but the button position didn't change.

Comment: Nice one :) You can now add float: right;. Change <td width="400" align="left"> to <td width="400" align="left" style="float:right"> let me know if it works

Comment: I changed       <form name="theform">
  <table width="600"> 
to:
                <form name="theform">
  <table width="600" align="right"> 

And I got all the buttons on the right of the page. 
But I want them on the left.
So, when I do it "align=left", the buttons do not go to the very left. They go a bit on the left but stay where the map ends. It seems there is something below the map that doesn't allow the buttons to go below it.